# R ggplot viridis change the color gradient

Tags: r, ggplot2, viridis

Hello I am plotting scatter plot using R ggplot for coloring using virdis, I wanted split the color legend to get more contrast between ranges currently legend having 1000,2000,3000,4000 In between this split this to get more color currently my code looking as below

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library("viridis")

df <- tibble(gene   = sample.int(5000),aceth  = rnorm(5000),acvitd = rnorm(5000))
df$log_mean=log(df$gene)
p=ggplot(df, aes(aceth, acvitd))+
  geom_point(aes(color =gene)) +
  theme(legend.position = "top")+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))

p=p+ theme(legend.position = "top") +
     scale_color_viridis(option = "A",
     name = "mean",
     guide = guide_colourbar(direction = "horizontal",
     barheight = unit(4, units = "mm"),
     barwidth = unit(100, units = "mm"),
     draw.ulim = F,
     title.hjust = 0.5,
     label.hjust = 0.5, title.position = "top"))
```

How I wanted my graph look like

[image]

can anyone suggest me

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for `scale_colour_vridis_b` to bin your colours?

```r
df <- tibble(gene   = sample.int(5000),aceth  = rnorm(5000),acvitd = rnorm(5000))
df$log_mean=log(df$gene)
p=ggplot(df, aes(aceth, acvitd))+
  geom_point(aes(color = - (aceth + acvitd))) +
  theme(legend.position = "top")+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))

p+ theme(legend.position = "top") +
     scale_colour_viridis_b(option = "A", values = 0:10 /10, breaks = 0:5 - 2.5)
```

[image]

Comment: yes  exactly same can you please explian how this values and breaks work.